# SQL CE - Select latest date

Tags: sql-server-ce

I've been having a lot of problems with SQL CE and this is just one of them.

I'm trying to get a row from another table with the latest date but getting errors with this query:

> SELECT      Projects.Client, Projects.Name, Projects.PO_No,
>   Projects.PO_Date, Projects.Facility,
>
> (SELECT  top (1)    Remarks FROM          Status WHERE Proj_ID = @1 ORDER BY Date DESC ),
>
> ...a couple of more columns here...
>
> FROM          Projects LEFT OUTER JOIN
>                           Collections AS b ON Projects.Proj_ID = b.Proj_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
>                           Imp AS c ON Projects.Proj_ID = c.Proj_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
>                           Acceptance AS d ON Projects.Proj_ID = d.Proj_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
>                           Billing AS e ON Projects.Proj_ID = e.Proj_ID WHERE      (Projects.Proj_ID = @1)

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's the error

> --------------------------- Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express
>   --------------------------- SQL Execution Error.
>
> Executed SQL statement: SELECT      Projects.Client, Projects.Name,
>   Projects.PO_No, Projects.PO_Date, Projects.Facility,
>
> (SELECT  top (1)    Remarks
>
> FROM          Status
>
> ORDER BY Date DESC ),
>
> ```
>   ...
> ```
>
> Error Source: SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider Error Message: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number =
>   4,Token line offset = 2,Token in error = SELECT ]

Comment: @leppie Sorry, I edited the post.

Comment: Perhaps it requires an alias?

Comment: @leppie Just tried right now, still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't sub `select` in SQL CE, that's the issue.